# if query does not exist, redirect to another page

Tags: php, redirect, web

This code only redirects to `notenrolled.php` even if the input value is correct. I want it to continue the process if the value entered is correct. Is there something wrong with my code?

```
<?php
//Setup connection to the database 
$connect = mysql_pconnect("localhost", "root", "") 
or die(mysql_error()); 

//Connect to the database 
mysql_select_db("dbgis", $connect) or die(mysql_error());

$query  = "SELECT * from tbl_student WHERE stud_id= '$stud_id' ";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$totalrows = mysql_num_rows($result);


while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    header("Location: yesno.php");
}

if($totalrows != 0)
{
    header("Location: notenrolled.php");
}

?>
```

---

I tried the `die();` and it seems to be working because it just says a redirection looping error with `yesno.php`. So I think I might have put the code in the wrong `.php` page.

The flow is like this: I have a `guard.php` page where I could search a `query(stud_id)` using my search form in the page. I then want to check whether the query exists and if it doesn't, I want it to redirect to `notenrolled.php` else if the query is found, I want it to proceed to `yesno.php`.

Answer (score 1):

When you set a Location header, you ALWAYS immediately follow it with `exit` or `die()`.

(Only if you truly understand what you are doing, might you not immediately use it, but at your own risk.)

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do it is this:

```
if($totalrows>0)
  header("Location: yesno.php");

else
 header("Location: notenrolled.php");
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if($totalrows == 0)
{
    header("Location: notenrolled.php");
    die();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($totalrows > 0)
{   // has results
    header("Location: yesno.php");
    exit(0);
}
else
{   // no result
    header("Location: notenrolled.php");
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: --------EDIT---------

i tried the die(); and it seems to be working because it just says a redirection looping error with yesno.php. So i think i might have put the code in the wrong .php page. 

The flow is like this: i have a guard.php page where i could search a query(stud_id) using my search form in the page. I then want to check whether the query exists and if it doesn't, i want i t to redirect to notenrolled.php else if the query is found, i want it to proceed to yesno.php.

Comment: yes, you have put the redirection to yesno.php in the wrong place, it shouldn't be within a while loop, especially when there is no die() or exit() after it. if you don't put a die() or exit() after it, it won't just go, it will finish its looping first.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should not use `while` just to evaluate if there is a record.

   ```
   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
   {
     header("Location: yesno.php");
   }
   ```
2. Your code always redirects to `notenrolled.php` because of the codition:

   ```
   if($totalrows != 0)
   {
       header("Location: notenrolled.php");
   }
   //this block will always be true if your $totalrows is greater than 0
   ```

The solution: check `$totalrows` if is greater than 0

```
if ($totalrows > 0){
   header("Location: yesno.php");
} else {
   header("Location: notenrolled.php");
}
```

Comment: i tried this and i also tried including the die(); or exit(0); and it seems to be working because it just says a redirection looping error or header already sent error with yesno.php. So i think i might have put the code in the wrong .php page or something. i have a guard.php page where i could search a query(stud_id) using my search form in the page. I then want to check whether the query exists and if it doesn't, i want i t to redirect to notenrolled.php else if the query is found, i want it to proceed to yesno.php.

Answer (score 0):

u can use php function [mysql_affected_rows](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php) to see number off affected rows in **SELECT**,

```
if (mysql_affected_rows() == 0){
  header("Location: notenrolled.php");
} else {
    header("Location: yesno.php");
}
```